# Inserting Excel to Sql database SQLBulkCopy method

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to insert Excel data into SQL Server 2008 database. I tried the `SqlBulkCopy` method to try to insert my data to the database and it runs without error, but it inserts each Excel record twice into the database. (The original data has 249 records, the inserted data has 498 records).

I tried setting one of the columns as a unique primary key, but I got an error:

> Cannot duplicate key on .... etc

which again, seems to imply that the records are being inserted twice.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    clearold()
End Sub

Protected Sub Upload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Upload and save the file
    Dim excelPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath)

    Dim connString As String = ""
    Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Select Case extension
        Case ".xls"
            '    'Excel 97-03
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel03ConString").ConnectionString
        Case ".xlsx"
            'Excel 07 or higher
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Excel07+ConString").ConnectionString
    End Select
    connString = String.Format(connString, excelPath)
    Using excel_con As New OleDbConnection(connString)
        excel_con.Open()
        Dim sheet1 As String = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing).Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
        Dim dtExcelData As New DataTable()


        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(14) {New DataColumn("ServerName", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("ITI PL", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("ITAG PL", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Group 0/1/2/3", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Impact", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("RMIF Template", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("In Current Patching Cycle?", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("IP", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Patch Frequency", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Last Patch Date", GetType(Date)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Next Patch Date", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Domain", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Server Type", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Project", GetType(String)), _
                                                        New DataColumn("Operating System", GetType(String))})

        Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter((Convert.ToString("SELECT * FROM [") & sheet1) + "]", excel_con)
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData)
        End Using
        excel_con.Close()


        Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
            Using sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
                'Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Excel"


                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ServerName", "ServerName")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ITI PL", "ITI PL")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ITAG PL", "ITAG PL")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Group 0/1/2/3", "Group 0/1/2/3")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Impact", "Impact")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("RMIF Template", "RMIF Template")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("In Current Patching Cycle?", "In Current Patching Cycle?")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("IP", "IP")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Patch Frequency", "Patch Frequency")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Last Patch Date", "Last Patch Date")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Next Patch Date", "Next Patch Date")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Domain", "Domain")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Server Type", "Type")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Project", "Project")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Operating System", "OS")



                con.Open()
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData)
                con.Close()


            End Using
        End Using

    End Using


End Sub

Sub clearold()
    db.OpenConn()
    Try
        Dim sql As String = "delete from Excel"
        db.ExecuteUpdate(sql)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    db.CloseConn()
End Sub
```

I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2008.

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with MySQL.

Comment: Check to see what's in the datatable when you step through with the debugger.

Comment: Hi anyone? Been struggling.